# ga() javascript function visibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have to use some third-party function, which is in turn calling google analytics ga(), as follows:

```
window.somefunc = function() {
   ...
   ga(...);
   ...
}
```

When "somefunc" is called from JS code loaded with the page, it works perfectly well.

But once I try to call it from the code loaded by ajax (with jquery "load"), it ends up with:

```
ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```

Why does it happen and how could I fix that?

Comment: Is the Google Analytics code loaded before the third-party function?

Comment: Sure, otherwise it won't work even in the first case.

Comment: Beyond that, I personally can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

load() - in this case it is a DOM load, but JS not complete (window load).
Use ga() after all js scripts done.
In google tag manager you can run scripts after all this events.